# Easy way to call REST API for c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am coming from JS and learning C# and I am trying to call to an API, I am having issues with the way I am calling it now and data seems to keep coming back as null. Can anyone help? Also is there an easier way to call an API with a library similar to Axios in JS? Everything with C# seems to be SO involved for even small tasks and its kind of a annoying, but I am going to keep trying.

This is the error I get for @Model.FullList:

"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null."

Here is the ViewModel and View
ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class MissingPersonsModel
    {
        public string FullList { get; set; }

        public async Task GetMissingPeople()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://fbimissingpersonapi.azurewebsites.net/v1/all");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                FullList = responseBody;

                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.MissingPersonsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MissingPersons";
}

<h1>MissingPersons</h1>


<div>
    @Model.FullList
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell because you haven't given us the URL and we cannot know what the response is `FullList = responseBody;`

Comment: "*there an easier way to call an API with a library similar to Axios in JS*" - is 2 lines not easy ?

Comment: Just added the URL @JeremyThompson

Comment: At what point do you call `GetMissingPeople` to set the list, I don't see it

Comment: @Charlieface I assumed this runs automatically? I set FullList = "Jaysnel" directly below client and it ran just fine, so I assumed it ran automatically? Sorry if it sounds stupid, ive only been working with C# for a few days.

Comment: What, no. If you set `FullList` manually, it will have a value. In your code, you only set it via that function, which you don't call

Comment: RestSharp ( https://restsharp.dev/ ) is a common library  for calling out to APIs

Comment: Thank you @KeithNicholas , this is exactly what I was looking for. Just trying to get a project up and running!

Comment: Personally i wouldn't be pointing anyone to RestSharp these days. The HttpClient class is streamlined and powerful enough to do most things with out all the abstractions, quirks and bad habits of RestSharp

Comment: One note, assuming you are going to be calling this more than once... Don't create an `HttpClient` instance for each request.  Create one and let it hang around.  Even better, look into the HttpClientFactory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused with how MVC fits together.

What you need to do is create a Model 'MissingPersonsModel" and deserialise the JSON into a `List<MissingPersonsModel>`.

To do this copy the JSON and run it through https://json2csharp.com/ to get your Model. Then you put any business logic in the Controller that returns the Model to the View.

**Model:**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class MissingPersonsModel{
        [JsonProperty("Date(s)ofBirthUsed")]
        public string DateSOfBirthUsed { get; set; } 
        public string Hair { get; set; } 
        public string Eyes { get; set; } 
        public string Height { get; set; } 
        public string Weight { get; set; } 
        public string Sex { get; set; } 
        public string Race { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Details { get; set; } 
        public string SubmitaTip { get; set; } 
        public bool Found { get; set; } 
        public string Headshot { get; set; } 
        public string Age { get; set; } 
        public string PlaceofBirth { get; set; } 
        public string ScarsandMarks { get; set; } 
        public string Nationality { get; set; } 
        public string Occupation { get; set; } 
        public string Languages { get; set; } 
        public string Build { get; set; } 
        public string Citizenship { get; set; } 
        public string Complexion { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();    
    public class MissingPersonsController
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()   // or call it GetMissingPeople() depending on the URL Route
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://fbimissingpersonapi.azurewebsites.net/v1/all");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                List<MissingPersonsModel> listMissingPersonsModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MissingPersonsModel>>(responseBody);

                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);

                return View(listMissingPersonsModel);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.MissingPersonsModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MissingPersons";
}
<h1>MissingPersons</h1>
<ul>       
      @if (Model!= null)
      {
           foreach (var person in Model)
           {
                 <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => person.Name)</li>
           }
      }
</ul>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: Although the RestSharp library ended up working for me, I do like this example as it gives me a good way to learn from especially with structure, but I have 2 questions for you, I noticed you're calling your logic in Controller, Ive seen a ton of examples call this in View Model instead. Any particular reason you did it this way?

I get a "The name 'View' does not exist in the current context" and that I also need to return a value in the catch statement. A weird error for sure(atleast to me, since by background is not in C#). Any reason for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of MVC you're using, best bet is to follow a walk through tutorial or video.